# Evaluating $\lim_{x → 4}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-7}-3}{4-\sqrt{3x+4}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> How can I find
> $$\lim_{x → 4}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-7}-3}{4-\sqrt{3x+4}}$$

I know the domain of the function is any real number except 4, but how can I eliminate the zero denominator?

Comment: What "zero denominator"?  At $x=4$, the denominator is $(4 - \sqrt{8}) \neq 0.$

Comment: Maybe the author swapped the numerator and the denominator. At $x=4$ the numerator is $0$. Edit: The function has been edited, this is no longer the case.

Comment: Looks like it is continuous in a neighborhood of the limit. I hesitate to answer since it seems like a typo.

Comment: Yes I agree. If there isn't any typo in your question you can simply plug in $x=4$ in your expression.

Comment: Your usage of parenthesis is awkward.

Comment: Maybe they wanted this $$\lim_{x \to 4}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-7}-3}{4-\sqrt{3x+4}}$$ which gives $-\frac{32}{9}$

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean! Sorry for the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally believe you should use l'hôpital. Differentiate both numerator and denominator if you get 0/0 or inf/inf. Then, evaluate at 4. So, in this case we would get the square root of $\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-7}}$. Now, evaluate at 4 yielding 4/3. Doing the same with the denominator, we get $-\dfrac{3}{2\sqrt{3x+4}}$ which evaluates to -3/8 at 4. Dividing 4/3 by -3/8 yields -32/9.

Answer (score 2):

Note that there are no singularities in the denominator, therefore you can do direct substitution.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 4}\frac{\sqrt{(x^2-7)-3}}{4-\sqrt{3x-4}}&=\frac{\sqrt{4^2-7-3}}{4-\sqrt{3(4)-4}}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{6}}{4-\sqrt{10}}\\
&=\frac{2\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{15}}{3}
\end{align*}

Comment: The question has been edited now, so you might want to change your answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x → 4}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-7}-3}{4-\sqrt{3x+4}}=\lim_{x → 4}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-7}-3}{4-\sqrt{3x+4}} \times \dfrac{4+\sqrt{3x+4}}{4+\sqrt{3x+4}}\times \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-7}+3}{\sqrt{x^2-7}+3} \\= \dfrac{(x^2-16)(4+\sqrt{3x+4})}{3(4-x)(\sqrt{x^2-7}+3)}$$

Now cancel the factor $x-4$ from numerator and denominator and plug $x=4$ to get the answer.